# Linear Complementarity Problem - multiple solutions, which one will it find?

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

If I have a inequality constrained system:

```
w = Mz + q <= 0, z<=0, z^T w = 0
```

that for some given properties `M` and `q` has multiple solutions, is there any way of determining which of the LCP solutions `(w,z)` Lemke's algorithm will find? As there are no means of providing an initial guess, I assume the algorithm will find the nonlinear solution `(w,z)` that is closest to the linear solution `(w,0)`. But how would I determine what can be considered "close"?